# Automatic sign conversion for operations on math-vector like class

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I have a custom vector (as used in math context not `std::vector`) which is templatized over the element type.
It also provides explicit conversion from other types.

In short:

```
template <typename T>
struct Point
{
    T x, y;
    Point(const T x, const T y): x(x), y(y) {}
    Point(const Point& other): x(other.x), y(other.y){}
    template<typename U>
    explicit Point(const Point<U>& pt): x(static_cast<T>(pt.x)), y(static_cast<T>(pt.y)) {}
    Point& operator+=(const Point& right);
    friend Point operator+(Point left, const Point& right) { return (left+=right); }

};
```

Now I'm using typedefs with signed type for positions and unsigned types for sizes. But I find that I need to combine those to very often which gets cumbersome with conversions. See:

```
typedef Point<int> Pos;
typedef Point<unsigned> Extent;

Pos pos = ...;
Extent size = ...;
std::cout << "The outside is: " << (pos + Pos(size));
```

What I would want is that unsigned types are automatically converted to signed types but not the other way round so I can simply write `pos + size`.
Is this easily possible?

Note on reasoning: I can combine signed and unsigned base types like `5 + 6u` which results in the <del>signed</del> unsigned type.
Edit: But combining a position (signed) and an extent (unsigned) should result in a new position.

Even better would be, if the automatic conversion only applies if you use a mathematical operator.

Edit: C++98 only, but boost is allowed

Comment: Just overload `operator+` for only that template type.

Comment: Position+=Size is ok, but you want to block Size+=Position?  What if Position is double, but size is unsigned int?

Comment: Second, there are mathematically two kinds of signed 2-vectors; positions *and distances*.  Adding positions is nonsense (NY + Kansas wut?); adding distances makes sense (NY to Kansas, plus Kansas to Texas), and position+distance (NY + NY to Kansas) makes sense.  Distance+=Position is nonsense (Increase NY to Kansas by Texas).  Scaling distances makes sense (1/2 NY to Kansas), scaling positions does not (1/2 Kansas).  Default constructed distances are zero; default constructed positions are null.  Sizes are unsigned *distances*, not unsigned *positions*.  Do you want to go this far?

Comment: @Yakk I treat position and offset the same (signed) because some positions might be relative (hence offsets). Sizes are unsigned as written. Combining 2 positions means treating one as an offset to the other which makes sense (offset=distance=relative position)

Comment: @RickAstley That would be quite cumbersome as I might have shorts, longs, floats, etc as the template type which results in a very big matrix of possible combinations

Answer (score 3):

You can write your `operator+` as free function that uses as return type "the type that is the result of adding the two types", for example:

```
template <typename T>
Point<T> make_point(T x, T y)
{
  return Point<T>(x, y);
}



template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(Point<T> const & lhs, Point<U> const & rhs)
// -> decltype(make_point(lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y))
{
  return make_point(lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y);
}
```

where `make_point` just does some type deduction for us and the `auto` return type of `operator+` also does type deduction for us (you can do it "by hand" using `decltype` and `std::declval`-constructs). You need at least a c++14 compiler for that to work (c++11 if you un-comment the trailing return type). You can, of course, use similar code for `operator-`, `operator*` and so on.

Comment: This is actually an amazing solution! This makes everything consistent with the standard type conversion (what is the word here? decay?) conventions with the least possible code.   
However I'm stuck with C++98 for a while, which I just added to the question.   
Also to make this complete: C++17 does not even require the `make_point` function.

Comment: One problem with this approach: It does not allow implicit type conversion. E.g. I have another struct which is implicitly convertible to `Point<int>` but the `operator+` cannot be found. Possible make this a friend function? Although I don't like the definitions inside the class.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to declare an overload `operator+` in a way that allows it to accept `Point<>` classes with different type parameters.

Secondly, you could rely on `std::common_type` to choose the correct result type between the two. I.e. the common arithmetic type that avoids a narrowing conversion:

```
template <typename T>
struct Point
{
    // as before, including your original operator+

  template<typename S, typename U,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<S, U>::value>::type* = nullptr, 
    typename ResType = typename std::common_type<S, U>::type>
  friend Point<ResType> operator+(const Point<S>& left, const Point<U>& right) {
    return Point<ResType>{left} + Point<ResType>{right};
  }
};
```

The slightly convoluted `enable_if` in the middle is a SFINAE technique to avoid a GCC redefinition error when `S` and `U` are the same.

Comment: This answer does help me although it can be improved so it suits my needs: Combine it with the answer from @MadScientiest to make this a free function. Then get rid of the `enable_if` as you use it for the same type function too and lastly do the deduction of `ResType` in the return type and the function and also use boost to make it C++98 only.

Comment: Just noticed that neither answer acutally solves the problem. Combining unsigned and signed types in C++ leads to unsigned types which I thought was signed.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answers by @MadScientiest and @StoryTeller I used the following:
First a trait to get me the result type

```
template<typename T>
struct TryMakeSigned
{
    typedef typename boost::conditional<
        boost::is_integral<T>::value,
        boost::make_signed<T>,
        boost::common_type<T>
    >::type::type type;
};
/// Creates a mixed type out of types T and U which is
/// the common type of T & U AND signed iff either is signed
/// fails for non-numeric types with SFINAE
template<typename T, typename U, bool T_areNumeric = boost::is_arithmetic<T>::value && boost::is_arithmetic<U>::value>
struct MixedType;

template<typename T, typename U>
struct MixedType<T, U, true>
{
    typedef typename boost::common_type<T, U>::type Common;
    // Convert to signed iff least one value is signed
    typedef typename boost::conditional<
        boost::is_signed<T>::value || boost::is_signed<U>::value,
        typename TryMakeSigned<Common>::type,
        Common
    >::type type;
};
```

And second use that for non-member operators:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline Point<typename detail::MixedType<T, U>::type> operator+(const Point<T>& lhs, const Point<U>& rhs)
{
    typedef typename detail::MixedType<T, U>::type Res;
    return Point<Res>(lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y);
}
```

This does however not consider implicit conversions. To have those declare the function as a friend function inside the class (omit the `typename T`)